# Removing Odoo 9 from Ubuntu 14.04 desktop?

Tags: odoo, ubuntu-14.04, odoo-9

I want to uninstall Odoo 9 and reinstall in my linux system. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just follow these steps

```
service odoo-server stop
```

## Remove config file(s)

```
rm -f /etc/odoo-server.conf
rm -f /etc/odoo.conf
```

## Remove application code

```
rm -R /opt/odoo
```

## Remove startup process

```
update-rc.d -f odoo-server remove
rm -f /etc/init.d/odoo-server
```

## Remove logs

```
rm -R /var/log/odoo
```

## Remove databases

```
sudo service postgresql stop
apt-get remove postgresql -y
apt-get --purge remove postgresql\* -y
rm -r -f /etc/postgresql/
rm -r -f /etc/postgresql-common/
rm -r -f /var/lib/postgresql/
```

## Delete users and groups

```
userdel -r postgres
groupdel postgres
```

To Remove postgre
find the file `pg_hba.conf` - it may be located, for example in `/etc/postgresql-9.1/pg_hba.conf`.

```
cd /etc/postgresql-9.1/
```

## Back it up

```
cp pg_hba.conf pg_hba.conf-backup
```

## place the following line (as either the first uncommented line, or as the only one):

```
local  all   all   trust
```

restart your PostgreSQL server (e.g., on Linux:)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

you can now connect as any user. Connect as the superuser postgres (note, the superuser name may be different in your installation. In some systems it is called pgsql, for example.)

```
psql -U postgres
```

Reset password

```
ALTER USER my_user_name with password 'my_secure_password';
```

Restore the old `pg_hba.conf` as it is very dangerous to keep around

```
cp pg_hba.conf-backup pg_hba.conf
```

restart the server, in order to run with the safe `pg_hba.conf`

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Comment: if you've installed `wkhtmltopdf`and `wkhtmltoimage` you might want to delete them as well, the symbolic links can be found at : `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf` and `/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage` respectively.